# VBA search box to look across not down

Tags: excel, vba, search

Sorry if my previous question was unclear, but I am looking for a fix for the following code.

The code below is used as a basic search box to locate a name in a large table, highlight and select. The original code works perfectly as it searches the column and returns a question to confirm if it is the correct name. If you select "NO" it will continue to search until you get the correct reply.

I would like to use this code on another one my sheets, that is identical in many ways, but due to my company using older excel I was forced to swap the names to be listed across the row. I thought a could just change the search criteria to look across, but as the code was REF# column letter and the code converts to number, I now get and error.

I guess this is a simple fix and just requires the VAR's to be correctly referenced, but this is beyond my butchering skills.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub SearchNameNext()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim Prompt As String
  Dim RetValue As String
  Dim Found As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim ColCnt As Long
  Dim Correct As String
  Dim StartRow As String

'Unlock2'   sub code to unlock sheets

'Range("C:BC").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Range("E10").Select

StartCol = "E"

  Prompt = ""

  With Sheets("RECORD")
    Do While True

      RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Who are you looking for?")

      If RetValue = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If

TryAgain:

      Set Rng = .Rows(9).Find(What:=RetValue, After:=.Range(StartCol & "9"), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Prompt = "I could not find """ & RetValue & """"
      Else
        ColCnt = Rng.Column
        Found = Range(ColCnt & "9").Value '    ERROR on this line, as ColCnt is given number value
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Range(ColCnt & "10").Select

        Output = MsgBox("Are you looking for """ & Found & "", vbYesNoCancel)

        If Output = 6 Then
'Output = 6(Yes)
Range("C7").Value = Found
ElseIf Output = 7 Then
'Output = 7(No)
StartCol = ColCnt
GoTo TryAgain
Else
'Output = 2(Cancel)
'Lock2'  sub code to lock sheets
Exit Sub
End If


      End If
      Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
    Loop

  End With
'Lock2'  sub code to lock sheets
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set Rng = .Rows(2).Find(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cells(rowNumber,columnNumber)` to refer to columns by numbers, with Column A being 1 column B being 2 and so on.
So `Range("B1")` becomes `cells(1,2)`

Looking at your code it looks like you using `columns("E:E").Find` to search along a down a column, so you will have to change this to the row you want to search along. 
`rows("1:1").find`

Then to work out which column the found value is in you can use `ColCrnt = Rng.Column` instead of `RowCrnt = Rng.Row`

So your code should look something like this (changes highlighted with 'Changed) 
Type this from my phone so couldnt check it

`

```
Sub SearchName()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim Prompt As String
  Dim RetValue As String
  Dim Found As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim ColCrnt As Long 'Changed
  Dim Correct As String
  Dim colRow As String  'changed
  Dim StartCol as long 'changed
Unlocker

Range("C:BC").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Range("F10").Select

StartCol = 1 'Changed

  Prompt = ""

  With Sheets("RECORD")
    Do While True

  RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Who are you looking for?")

  If RetValue = "" Then
    Exit Do
  End If

TryAgain:


  'Changed (so looks along first row) and the after parameter
  Set Rng = .Rows("1:1").Find(What:=RetValue, After:=.cells(1,StartCol), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

  If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Prompt = "I could not find """ & RetValue & """"
  Else
    ColCrnt = Rng.Column 'Changed
    'Changed  the number here needs to matched the row number in search 
    Found = cells(1,ColCrnt).Value         
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Range("F" & RowCrnt).Select

    Output = MsgBox("Are you looking for """ & Found & "", vbYesNoCancel)

    If Output = 6 Then
       'Output = 6(Yes)
        'At this point ColCrnt will give you the column number of the found value
        'Range("C" & RowCrnt & ":" & "BC" & RowCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    ElseIf Output = 7 Then
       'Output = 7(No)
       StartCol= ColCrnt
       GoTo TryAgain
    Else
       'Output = 2(Cancel)
        Locker
        Exit Sub
    End If

  End If
  Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
Loop



End With
Locker
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Thanks I Donaldson, with a couple of tweaks and a bit of tidying, it works like a dream.